# sudo Virtualbox returns "Qt WARNING: libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile" error 17.04

Tags: virtualbox, sudo, qt, 17.04

So I just installed ubuntu 17.04 and launch Virtualbox as `sudo` for the first time and I get the following error:

```
$ sudo virtualbox
Qt WARNING: QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'
Qt WARNING: libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
```

Although Virtualbox does launch, I'm a bit worried by this error as I don't know what it means. Can anyone help me resolve this?

Comment: Warnings are not errors.

Comment: Actually we should not run VirtualBox with `sudo`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Graphical applications should not be launched using sudo. This is the cause of the first warning. Not sure why you would need to launch virtualbox using sudo, but if you do you should use gksudo:

```
gksudo virtualbox
```

A search of the second warning suggests it isn't anything to worry about. It apparently means that one or more of the png files used has an old sRGB profile. Everything should still work correctly.

Comment: Thank's for the detailed response. What's the difference between gksudo and sudo?

Comment: No problem. Take a look [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo#Graphical_sudo). This explains in more detail.

Comment: once again, thanks for being so kind and helpful